# Why doesn't it print "hello" first?

Tags: python

In this code:

```
print("Hello " + input("What is Your name?")+ "!")
```

When I run it, it prints "What is your name?" Why doesn't it print "hello" first? It should ask the user for input for his name.

Comment: The concatenation of the three strings will not take place until *input()* returns

Comment: *it should ask the user for input for his name* - that's what it is doing, no?

Comment: What you are trying to say is that if a function is found inside another, the function inside is executed first

Comment: Do you understand the order in which the code is evaluated/executed? It first evaluates `input("What is Your name?")`, then the concatenation - `"Hello " + "some_user_input" + "!"` and then the `print("Hello some_user_input!")`

Comment: @RagaeyM.Ragaa yes, and it couldn't be any other way. If you have an expression like `function1(function2(x))`, it's not possible to evaluate function1 before function2.

Comment: @slothrop At least, not in Python (or any other language that uses eager evaluation). In a lazy language like Haskell, you can write `f (g x)` (equivalent to Python `f(g(x))`, and if `f` never uses its argument, `g` never gets called.

Comment: I'd say it's the "default behaviour" of languages that arguments to functions are eagerly evaluated: before the function/method can be called, all the parameter values must have been evaluated (which includes calling any other functions as necessary). The languages that *don't* do that (such as Haskell as mentioned by chepner) are definitely in the minority.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like in mathematics, anything in inner parentheses has to be evaluated first. So Python does

```
input("What is your name?")
```

and then performs `print()` on the concatenation of the resulting strings in the argument list.

Answer (score 2):

`input()` waits for -- well -- user input.
So if you enter a name, it will read said input and continue executing the rest of the code (string concatenation and print):

```
>>> print("Hello " + input("What is Your name?\n")+ "!")
What is Your name?
Foo  # typed by you!
Hello Foo!
```